# How to fix 'Permission denied' error when installing Visual Studio?

Tags: software-installation, visual-studio-code

Got this error while trying to install Visual Studio code:

> Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/omar/Downloads/code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

How do I fix this?

Comment: hey sir ive already fixed this by using : dpkg -i instead of apt thanks in advance for the help tho!

Comment: sorry im new here i thought it was a general support quetions thing

Answer (score 0):

answer :
sudo dpkg -i code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb
or
use snap install

Comment: i was using "sudo apt ./code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb"

Comment: You missed that the command would have been `sudo apt install ./code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb`

Comment: Sorry that’s what I meant sudo apt install not sudo apt